# Equation solving involving terms inside roots

Tags: quadratics

How do I solve

$$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}+\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2} = x$$

**My Try** I tried to take the first term as $t$ but then I had to square both sides twice and that led to a complex bi quadratic. I'm not sure even that'll solve the problem.

*guys please let me know what are different possible ways to tackle problems like these, and how would you go about on solving this particular one*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}+\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2} = x\iff \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2} = x-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}.$$ Squaring

$$x-\frac{1}{x} = x^2+1-\frac{1}{x}-2x\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}.$$ Simplifying

$$x = x^2+1-2x\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}.$$ That is

$$2x\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}=x^2-x+1.$$ Squaring again

$$4x^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)=x^4-2x^3+3x^2-2x+1.$$ Thus, we get

$$x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+1=0.$$ That is

$$(x^2-x-1)^2=0.$$ This must be easy to solve.

Comment: At last, how did you figure out the factors for the degree 4 expression?

Comment: $\left(x^2+ax+b\right)^2=x^4+2ax^3+a^2 x^2+2 b x^2+2 a b x+b^2\quad$
Now compare with the coefficient of $x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+1\quad$
We have $a=-1$ and $x^4-2x^3+(2 b+1) x^2-2 b x+b^2$ and we have $2b+1=-1\to b=-1$ so the polynomial is $\left(x^2-x-1\right)^2\quad$ be careful because one of the solution is negative and is a fake solution

Comment: And, since we have squared, we might have introduced solutions, so don't forget to test the solutions found for the last equation in the original equation.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2} = \frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}+\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}}=\frac{x-1}{x}=1-\frac1x,$$ 
adding both equations gives $$2\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}=x-\frac{1}{x}+1.$$ That means $$x-\frac{1}{x}=1,$$ so we have $x=\phi$ (the Golden Ratio). The other solution $x=-\phi^{-1}$ does not satisfy the original equation, we must have $x>0$.

Comment: DId you see the beautiful sextic equation which came in an "answer" ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I had seen it, before it was edited (still shuddering ;). It was the main reason to look for a better way.

Comment: For sure and your approach is so simple ! Once more $\phi$ !! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: square one times you will get
$$x-\frac{1}{x}+1-\frac{1}{x}+2\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}=x^2$$
rearranging 
$$2\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}=x^2-x-\frac{2}{x}-1$$
an then you must square again
after squaring and sorting the Terms we get
$$(x^2-x-1)^2=0$$

Comment: This seems to be **totally wrong** !

Comment: ok i will have a look at  this equation

Comment: ok thank you it can be factorized!

Comment: This seems to be **totally wrong** !

Comment: it was wrong, i have changed it, thank you

Answer (score -2):

Hint:take $$a=x+\frac1x ,b=x-\frac1x$$
so $$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}+\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2} = x\\\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\frac{a+b}{2}$$

Comment: Note that $x-\frac 1x\ne 1-\frac 1x=b.$